# Linear layout in a scrollview does not occupies full height

Tags: android

I have a linear layout say V1, inside L1 i have a scrollview V2, Inside scrollview i have another linear layout V3, Now V3 has a gridtview V4. The pbm is that if my listview has say 6 items, only 2 are visible, for rest i have to scroll even when i see plenty of space left vacant. I set the background colors(Background color for V2:magenta, for V3 Green) and observed this:
V2 covers the entire V1
V3 covers only a fraction say 30% of V2,
V4 covers complete V3.
So I have done nearly everything i could follow to make V3 cover All of V2, but not success.I have wasted many hours on this, plz let me know if this has any solution.

//Scrollview Params V2
LinearLayout.LayoutParams svParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0F);

So all these things I tried do not work:

```
V3.getLayoutParams().height = V2.getHeight();
//((LinearLayout)gv.getParent()).getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

//((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)((LinearLayout)gv.getParent()).getLayoutParams()).weight = 1.0F;
//((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout)gv.getParent()).getParent()).getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
```

BUT if I give some hardcoded value for V4, it does increases the height of all its parent views,but I do not want to do that and that is not feasible in my application

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just use `setFillViewport(true)` on the `ScrollView`. This way, if the content of the `ScrollView` is smaller than the visible portion of the `ScrollView`, it will be expanded to fill that region.

Comment: I had to set android:layout_height="match_parent" in addition to setting the setFillViewport to true.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set android:layout_weight="1" in L1

Comment: Nope, that doesnt works and that shuldnt work also As scrollview is getting its full height but not the view inside scrollview, what should have been the ideal thing is set weight = 1.0F for V3, but That becomes a frame Layout for which there is no constructor that takes a weight argument!

Comment: Basically i think the problem can be narrowed down to Making framelayout(V3 in my case to occupy full height of its parent but it does not have weight thing in its constructor), The pbm i think is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575268/android-programmatic-frame-layout-used-as-a-button-how-to-fill-parent .But i cant his solution, as it is not relevent in my case :(