# Scrollview has padding? Linearlayout in Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem, I have a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView but the LinearLayout doesn't use all height of Screen. I don't know why. Please see my code. I need that LinearLayout use all height of screen

```
<ScrollView style="@style/scrollProfile">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/updateLinearLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
            style="@style/updateRelativeLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
                style="@style/profilImage" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProfileBackground"
                style="@style/imagenBackgroundProfile" />

            <LinearLayout style="@style/linearBlank">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPicture"
                    style="@style/buttonUpdateProfile" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/linearInputs"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <LinearLayout style="@style/linearInputEntry">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:text="First Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    style="@style/editTextEntryName" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout style="@style/linearInputEntry">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:text="Last Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastName"
                    style="@style/editTextEntryLastName" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout style="@style/linearInputEntry">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    style="@style/label"
                    android:text="Telephone" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/phone"
                    style="@style/editTextEntryPhone" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout style="@style/linearBlank">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/updateButton"
                style="@style/buttonSaveProfile" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView size:

[image: ScrollView size]

LinearLayout size:

[image]

And the styles are:

```
<style name="scrollProfile">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
</style>
<style name="updateLinearLayout">
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: use `android:fillViewport="true"` and check. Also voting to close this question as it is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear layout in a scrollview does not occupies full height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814230/linear-layout-in-a-scrollview-does-not-occupies-full-height)

Comment: But, the RelativeLayout has wrap_content, so when I put android:fillViewport the height of RelativeLayout chang to all

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`

Comment: But, the RelativeLayout has wrap_content, so when I put  android:fillViewport the height of RelativeLayout chang to all.